# Unable to import node_module in stencil components's .tsx file

Tags: node-modules, polyfills, stenciljs

I am importing eventsource object from node_module in stencil-components component.tsx file.

```
 import {NativeEventSource, EventSourcePolyfill} from 'event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.js'
```

so in above code if i do ctrl+click on eventsource.js it should go to the refrence but it is not showing anything. It is also not responding any error in visual studio editor.

this is my directory structure.

[image]

But it shows error at building that its not exported by eventsouce.js

> ```
> >     [ ERROR ]  TypeScript: src/dxp-notification.tsx:51:20
> >                Cannot find name 'NativeEventSource'.
> >     
> >          L50:  {
> >          L51:    var EventSource = NativeEventSource || EventSourcePolyfill
> ```

Am I missing any required configuration?
Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you figure out something ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just tried to import it like this :

`import eventsource from 'event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.js'`

And then use it like this

`eventsource.NativeEventSource` or `eventsource.EventSourcePolyfill`

This one seems working for me